# Where is the Windows Forms designer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I created a new Windows Forms form in C#, saved, and closed out. I came back to the project and my form was nowhere to be found.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to menu *View* → *Solution Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>).

There you can find your form and double-click it for the designer. If your Form is not there, either you have opened a wrong project or you have forgotten to save your Form.